# Bower: force update of local package

Tags: bower

I need to force bower to override a locally-defined dependency with a fresh copy. I assumed that `bower update <package>` would do the trick (even with a little extra `--force`). However, it stubbornly prefers whatever copy is installed under **bower_components**.

Consider the following layout (all in one codebase for now, sadly):

**shared/bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "mysharedstuff",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  ...
}
```

**client1/bower.json**

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "mysharedstuff": "../shared"
  }
}
```

The only way I can get a fresh copy of **shared/** is to explicitly delete the copy installed under **bower_components**. For example:

```
client1$> rm -rf bower_components/mysharedstuff
client1$> bower install
```

Is this a bug with how bower handles versioning of local dependencies? Or am I missing something simple?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. Might be a bug?

Comment: This seems to be the same issue: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/923

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just to update from the github issue you referenced.

```
bower --force update
```

will force update any packages in your bower.json.
Works in Bower > v1.3.6

Comment: Still have this bug(?) in bower 1.3.12, but this fix works. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting this answer (finally). I confirmed this works with a hosted, private repo. Local packages *should* work just the same. (I ran into this issue after mistakenly tagging a buggy version of an internal utils library)

Answer (score 1):

Because bower looking for latest TAG name in your repo. Specify your last commit with git tag.